# C# polymorphism with generic type and list

Tags: c#, generics, polymorphism

Maybe my question is simple or just stupid but I have following problem:

I have 2 polymorphic methods:

```
public void Index<T>(string alias, IEnumerable<T> items) where T : class
{
    var result = Client.IndexMany(items, alias);
    ExceptionHandling(result);
}

public void Index<T>(string alias, T item) where T : class
{
    var result = Client.Index(item, x => x.Index(alias));
    ExceptionHandling(result);
}
```

When I'm now trying to call the method which is getting a `List` with following command:

```
ClientService.Index(Alias, items.ToList());
```

Always the method `Index<T>(string alias, T item)`is getting called. How can I change it that Lists call the first Method and single objects call the second Method?

Comment: Have you tried to cast the `items` to an Enumerable? Like this: `items.AsEnumerable();`

Comment: You could explicitly specify the generic type.  Or better yet give these methods different names.  It seems like `IndexMany` would be the perfect name for the first one.

Comment: @juharr Thanks for your replay, but there must be a better solution for this  problem. I cant imagine that this could be so hard.

Comment: @ChristophKn Yes I tried it now, but it doesnt help.

Comment: Marius, @ChristophKn comment works. Try this : `ClientService.Index(Alias, items.ToList().AsEnumerable())`

Comment: @Pikoh The `ToList` shouldn't be needed unless `items` is something that exposes it's own `ToList` versus being something that implements `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: Yes,you are right @juharr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the problem with having the same name for a method (overloading) where the two overloads clearly do different things - you have a hint to the solution; elsewhere you have named the downstream methods `Index` and `IndexMany`.

Your two options are

1. [Name the methods differently, and appropriately](http://rextester.com/YIW92033)
2. [Explicitly cast your list to an `IEnumerable<T>` using `AsEnumerable()` extension method.](http://rextester.com/MRJ1164)

Answer (score 2):

***I have an alternative solution!***

You can use *parameter names* to differentiate the overloads!

You see, the first overload's second parameter is called `items`, whereas the second overload's second parameter is called `item`. Therefore, if you want to call the first overload, you just need:

```
ClientService.Index(Alias, items: items.ToList());
```

If you want the second instead, you can call:

```
ClientService.Index(Alias, item: items.ToList());
```

See the difference?

Clean and tidy! Tested on chsarppad: http://csharppad.com/gist/0d7f71c66079fefa680ea3f6afb2ed63

Answer (score 1):

You could specify the generic argument type e.g.

```
ClientService.Index<Item>(Alias, items.ToList());
```

Comment: There is a special meaning, why i put it generic. So your answer isnt very helpful.

Comment: @Marius - Your question was how to select the correct overload. If you have some other requirement you should put it in the question.

Comment: If i set the method generic, i dont want to change the generic to an explicit type of course.. So i think my question is right.

Comment: @Marius - You need to pick a type at the call site, or you have another generic parameter you can apply. You can't resolve overloads dynamically.